# Stopping creation of posts unless approved is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Afternoon All,

I have a model called snippet.rb and I would like only one user to post at a time until approved.

Would I run this as a custom validation or as an `after_create` in the snippet.rb.

The step process is below:

- User creates snippet
- Snippet submitted for approval
- No other snippets can be created until the previous one has been approved.

Could someone help me or point me in the direction of some documentation on how to do this.

Always appreciate the help. I'm trying to work through this in my head but cannot find anything to help.

Comment: please vote up my answer if you found it useful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your snippets_controller.rb

```
before_filter :check_last_snippet, :only => [:create]

private
def check_last_snippet
  redirect_to root_path unless Snippet.last.approved?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should use custom validation.

for example

```
validate :verify_for_not_approved_snippets

def verify_for_not_aproved_posts
  errors.add(:base, "error message") if "your condition here"
end
```

more detaily you can read at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations

Answer (score 0):

create a method in your user model and call this method before creating snippet

```
def check_snippet
  return true if user.snippets.blank? || (user.snippets.present? && user.snippets.where(approved: true).size > 1)
end
```

If this method returns true then only user can post snippet again. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use validate on create,

```
 validate :check_last_snippet_approved, :on => :create      

 def check_last_snippet_approved
   errors.add(:base, "could not add due to last snippet not approved") if !self.last.nil? && self.last.approved ==  false
 end
```